# How do I get the Commands of a laptop camera in powershell?

Tags: windows, webcam, powershell-4.0

I found online a way to get the commands of a Nikon D3000 Camera.
URL: https://ardalis.com/powershell-control-over-nikon-d3000-camera/

I want to do the same with my laptop Camera, but I can't find a way to it.
I got this command:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPEntity | where {$_.caption -match 'camera'}
```

And it gives me the output:

```
__GENUS                     : 2  
__CLASS                     : Win32_PnPEntity  
__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_LogicalDevice  
__DYNASTY                   : CIM_ManagedSystemElement  
__RELPATH        :Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\\VID_30C9&PID_000E&MI_00\\6&7B0B3D2&0&0000"  
__PROPERTY_COUNT            : 26  
__DERIVATION                : {CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}  
__SERVER                    : LAPTOP-SA63K2Q3  
__NAMESPACE                 : root\cimv2  
__PATH                      : \\LAPTOP-SA63K2Q3\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\\VID_30C9&PID_000E&MI_00\\6&7B0B3D2&0&0000"  
Availability                :  
Caption                     : HP Wide Vision HD Camera  
ClassGuid                   : {ca3e7ab9-b4c3-4ae6-8251-579ef933890f}  
CompatibleID                : {USB\Class_0e&SubClass_03&Prot_00, USB\Class_0e&SubClass_03, USB\Class_0e}  
ConfigManagerErrorCode      : 0  
ConfigManagerUserConfig     : False  
CreationClassName           : Win32_PnPEntity  
Description                 : USB-videoapparaat  
DeviceID                    : USB\VID_30C9&PID_000E&MI_00\6&7B0B3D2&0&0000  
ErrorCleared                :  
ErrorDescription            :  
HardwareID                  : {USB\VID_30C9&PID_000E&REV_0002&MI_00, USB\VID_30C9&PID_000E&MI_00}  
InstallDate                 :  
LastErrorCode               :  
Manufacturer                : Microsoft  
Name                        : HP Wide Vision HD Camera  
PNPClass                    : Camera  
PNPDeviceID                 : USB\VID_30C9&PID_000E&MI_00\6&7B0B3D2&0&0000  
PowerManagementCapabilities :  
PowerManagementSupported    :  
Present                     : True  
Service                     : usbvideo  
Status                      : OK  
StatusInfo                  :  
SystemCreationClassName     : Win32_ComputerSystem  
SystemName                  : LAPTOP-SA63K2Q3  
PSComputerName              : LAPTOP-SA63K2Q3
```

Comment: You start by referencing a blog post that uses `WIA.CommandDialog` com service to query connected devices - what happens if you try the same?

Comment: If I try the same and no device is connect to USB I get :  There is an unknown error in the WIA-device. At line:1 char:1
+ $device = $dialog.ShowSelectDevice()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException